# I try to add new record to recordset and get an error #3001

Tags: ms-access, vba

I hava a very simple code that adds new record to table in my Access Database. It worked for a while but now I get 3001 error on string ".AddNew".
I don't know what can cause this error. Any ideas?

```
Sub testAddNew()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rcs As DAO.Recordset, rcs2 As DAO.Recordset, rcsLength As Integer
Dim sqlQr As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rcs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenTable)
With rcs
    .MoveFirst
    .AddNew
    ![column1] = "test"
    .Update
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to give us the full error message instead of just "error #3001"?

Answer (score 0):

Open the correct recordset:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rcs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenTable)
With rcs2
    .AddNew
        ![column1].Value = "test"
    .Update
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
End With
```

or try with a query:

```
Set rcs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From Table1")
```

Comment: I made a typo while editing my code to insert on stackoverflow. Even with the right variable name I still get that error.

Comment: You can try with a query (see edited answer). If that also fails, something else is going on.